# Reading menu items from XML in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, menu

I am building a multilingual web site which will provide four languages. I will be using an asp:MenuItem control. For each language I want to read menu items' names from an XML document. 
XML draft can be thought as the following:

```
<root>
    <language>
        <en>
            <home>
                <link>Default.aspx</link>
                <text>Home</text>
           </home>
            <about>
                <link>About.aspx</link>
                <text>About</text>
            </about> 
        </en>
        <de>
            <home>
                <link>Default.aspx</link>
                <text>Hauptseite</text>
           </home>
           <about>
                <link>About.aspx</link>
                <text>Über</text>
            </about> 
        </de>
    </language>
</root>
```

I am not sure if the syntax and construction are correct. My other goal is about menu items order. The order must be same for all languages.

I want to know how to realize this. OR is there another and/or better way to do this.
Also my database is ready for content for both languages.

I do not want to work with if-else conditions.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If all languages should be the same structure, I would suggest a slightly different XML.

This groups the different names for the different languages together, which should be easier to manage should you need to change anything.

```
<root>
  <item>
    <link>default.aspx</link>
    <text>
      <en>Home</en>
      <de>Hauptseite</de>
    </text>
  </item>
  <item>
    <link>about.aspx</link>
    <text>
      <en>About</en>
      <de>Über</de>
    </text>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Actually XML solution is just an idea for me. I'd rather to know how to make it using .net's tools. I am sure there are strong tools but I do not know how to use them.